# Resolving long path (>260 char) limitation for accessing files/folders in latest Windows 10 build using Javascript

Tags: windows, path, limit, max-path

I am building a cordova windows application and get an error in accessing files and folders from my application that have path lengths greater than 260 characters because of the windows limitation. For accessing or creating new files and folders, currently, I am using Windows.Storage namespace of Windows (Runtime) API for Javascript with functions such as createFolderAsync, getFolderAsync, getFileFromPathAsync etc.

Recently, I heard that the latest build of Windows 10 has removed the 260 character limit for paths of files/folders. (Here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#maxpath)) But this is only available in some particular Win32 functions available in C++, and to call them in my app, I need to make a Windows Runtime component in C++. (1) Is there a way, I can leverage the latest changes in the latest Windows 10 build (version 1607) to directly create/access files and folders with path lengths > 260 chars? (2) Is this limitation still there in the javascript Windows libraries and do we really have no option but to involve win32 C++ APIs to do away with this problem? (3) Is windows considering to remove this limitation from all other libraries as well in the future?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Launch gpedit.msc (Windows + R)

Go to "Local Computer Policy" -> "Computer Configuration" -> "Administrative Templates" -> "System" -> "Filesystem"

Open "Enable Win32 long paths" and select Enabled

[image]

Comment: Or go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` set DWORD value `LongPathsEnabled` to 1